# ODE theorem with Lipschitz condition, understanding the definition of the solution of a first-order PDE and other questions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

1. We had a theorem given during the lecture, do you know what the name of this theorem is, and why it is true? It goes as follows:

> If $\: \forall _{i=1,...,n} \:\: f_i=f_i\left(x,\:y_1,\:....,\:y_n\right)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of $\left(x_o,\:y^o_1,\:...,\:y^o_n\right)$ and (also in that neighborhood) fulfills the Lipschitz condition with regard to $y_1,\:...,\:y_n$, then in the neighborhood of $x_o$ there exists exactly one solution for $\begin{cases}
>       y'_1 = f_1\left(x,\:y_1,\:....,\:y_n\right) \\ ... \\
>       y'_n = f_n\left(x,\:y_1,\:....,\:y_n\right) 
>     \end{cases} $  with the conditions $\begin{cases}
>       y_1\left(x_o\right)=y^o_1\\ ... \\
>       y_n\left(x_o\right)=y^o_n 
>     \end{cases} $

2. If we have our first integrals $\Phi _1,\:...,\:\Phi _n$ (from the general solution), then why are those first integrals linearly independent if $\:\nabla \Phi _1,\:...,\:\:\nabla \Phi _n$ are linearly independent?
3. If we have $\Phi =\Phi \left(x,\:y_{1},\:...,\:y_n\right)$ as a first integral, then why should it be that: $$ \frac{\partial \Phi }{\partial x}+f_1\left(x,\:y_1,\:...,\:y_n\right)\frac{\partial \Phi \:}{\partial y_1}+...+f_n\left(x,\:y_1,\:...,\:y_n\right)\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y_n}=0 $$
4. That's more of an arithmetical question I believe, but why exactly: $$(1)  \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:a_1\left(x\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+...+a_n\left(x\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}=\:0\:\Leftrightarrow \:\frac{dx_1}{a_1\left(x\right)}=...=\frac{dx_n}{a_n\left(x\right)} $$ (And also why $a_1\left(x,u\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+...+a_n\left(x,u\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}=\:b\left(x,u\right)\:\Leftrightarrow \:\frac{dx_1}{a_1}=...=\frac{dx_n}{a_n}=\frac{du}{b}$)
5. If $\:\: \begin{cases}
         \Psi _1\left(x_1,\:...,\:x_n\right)=C_1 \\ ... \\
         \Psi _{n-1}\left(x_1,\:...,\:x_n\right)=C_{n-1} 
       \end{cases} $ is a system of first integrals for (1), our solution would be $u=\Phi \left(\Psi _1,\:...,\:\Psi _{n-1}\right)$ where $\Phi$ is an arbritary function. I understand how we are able to calculate those $\Psi_{i}$, but why can $\Phi$ be arbritary?
6. We also had a geometric interpretation of 1st order PDEs given. The conditions we define on a three-dimensional first-order PDE define a curve, but the curve cannot intersect with itself. Why?

I'm sorry that I'm asking you a lot of questions right now, but Office Hours only last 1 hour and are once a week, and as far as I know other students from group also plan to go this week

Answer (score 1):

1. Picard-Lindelöf in its most local (and most common) version. By local tradition the names Lipschitz and Cauchy might also be used.
2. The $n$ first integrals provide a coordinate system for the solution curves. That is, $\Phi_k(x,y(t))=C_k$, and in principle the system $\Phi(x,z)=C$ should have, locally, only $z=y(x)$ as solution. The gradient condition is now nothing other than establishing the assumption of the implicit function theorem. If these are satisfied one has indeed a complete system of first integrals. Any other function that is constant on the solutions can then be expressed as a function of the values $C$.
3. First integrals are constant along solutions. Now apply the chain rule for the differentiation of $C=Φ(x,y(x))$ by $x$, giving
   $$
   0=∂_xΦ(x,y(x))·1+∂_{y_1}Φ(x,y(x))y_1'(x)+...+∂_{y_n}Φ(x,y(x))y_n'(x)
   $$
   and insert the differential equation.

---

Now you are switching to the first order PDE?

4. Take any curve $x(t)$ and apply the composition $u(x(t))$. Now apply the chain rule while differentiating for $t$,
   $$
   \frac{du(x(t))}{dt}=∂_{x_1}u(x(t))\dot x_1(t)+...+∂_{x_n}u(x(t))\dot x_n(t)
   $$
   Then compare with the PDE. So if the ODE system $\dot x_k(t)=\lambda(t)a_k(x(t))$ is satisfied, then $\frac{du(x(t))}{dt}=0$, so that $u(x(t))$ is a constant. Writing the fraction equation chain is just another way to express this,
   $$
   \frac{dx_k}{a_k(x)}=\lambda(t)dt=\frac{dx_j}{a_j(x)},
   $$
   but removing the emphasis from the parametrization by $t$, or now removing the free scaling function $\lambda(t)$, as any other parametrization of the same curves will lead to the same conclusions.
5. The value of $u$ is constant along the characteristic curves, and these curves are uniquely addressed by the values of the first integrals, $C=Φ(x(t))\implies u(x(t))=const$. Note that here you only have $n-1$ first integrals as functions of $x$ without $t$, so $Φ^{-1}(C)$ is a curve or a collection of them. So $u$ is a function of these first integrals. What that function precisely is, is determined by the boundary condition.
6. The system of first order ODE has only one solution per initial condition. This precludes any double points, that is crossings with different tangents. But one could for example have circles as characteristic curves. I think this point only applies to linear PDE of exactly the given type, one could easily expand to
   $$
   a_1(x,u(x))∂_{x_1}u(x)+...+a_n(x,u(x))∂_{x_n}u(x)=b(x,u(x))
   $$
   without losing too much of the theory of characteristic curves.

Comment: 2. We didn't have any functional dependence or something, but to be honest I don't really understand what you mean, by "non-trivial linear combination". I just don't see the reasoning you are presenting here, let's say we assume that those Phi are linearly independent but their gradients are linearly dependent, at which point will we get a contradiction?

Comment: 4. Could you maybe write it out please? Because I can't really follow what you mean

Comment: 3. I don't know what you mean, if I differentiate something constant by x I get zero, so where does the chain rule apply?

Comment: 5. I know understand it a little bit better but still it doesn't make sense to me why our solution u should be equal to something created with the help of our first integrals, why not something else (like if I have = b/du on the right side, then the solution is Psi of (Phi1, ...) is equal to 0 for some reason - why?)

Comment: 6. Our teacher also said that the curve's projection also should not have a intersection with itself, why does this matter? Also, even if the original curve has a intersection with itself, how does this result in having more than one solution? We are still moving on the same curve, on the same point

Comment: 2. The claim is the other way around, you can not have the gradients independent and the functions dependent. 5. I do not understand your example. 6. What projection precisely? You can get the situation where the shape of boundary and characteristic curves leads to multiple intersection which makes multiple, incompatible values for $u$ along that curve possible. I'm not sure this was the point...

Comment: 2. I just want to see why this claim has to be true, like on an example, because without an example I cannot grasp what you are trying to explain me. 5. If we have $a_1\left(x,u\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+...+a_n\left(x,u\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}=\:b\left(x,u\right)\:\Leftrightarrow \:\frac{dx_1}{a_1}=...=\frac{dx_n}{a_n}=\frac{du}{b}$ the solution to that would be $0=\Phi \left(\Psi _1,\:...,\:\Psi _{n}\right)$. What I don't understand, for both cases, is why do we even bother to define our solution like that, why do such solutions make sense?

Comment: 6. If it's a curve in 3D space then e.g. the projection on the XY plane (if x and y are it's variables), then our teacher said that also the projection of that curve cannot have intersections with itself